# Facebook Authentication gets stuck in Production - using Rails 2.3.11 omniauth 1.0.2 in EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, amazon-ec2, omniauth

For my Rails 2.3.11 app, I've Omniauth based facebook authentication working in my development environment- Ubuntu box. That works perfectly. However in production it just sits there.

Ultimately I believe it fails because of timeout. I believe its failing in handling the callback from facebook: =">http://ziptrips.in:8002/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQA7cFWwM4Yrvm3dlREWv8-sdassasadas-9xkDVptqLfsl1Bevb9w8dbbcl9sgCmYugkWycgbFjqxWZozuiLAOzAJ1WxAde8T2DpRpJmYBXSNT4NtgGOup2O2XDmiYlEzAGSePEMeMjqvRX2oUCqHw#*=*

Since mine is a Rails 2.3.11 app, here's how my omniauth.rb in initializers looks like:
ActionController::Dispatcher.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do #if you are using rails 2.3.x
provider :facebook, '1234123343', '6aec22dssadsaetcetc', :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_path => "/etc/ssl/certs"}},  :scope => 'email,offline_access,read_stream'
end

Here's relevant info:
Omniauth Gem : 1.0.2
omniauth-facebook gem: 1.2.0
Hosted in EC2

You can try it here: http://ziptrips.in/auth/facebook
I've made sure that facebook settings are correct.

Any help / pointers are really appreciated.

Thanks,
Navneet

Comment: I created a new instance on Amazon EC2 and on this instance everything works just fine. I think the issue had to do with the fact that I'd a lot of gems installed on my previous instance and I couldn't figure out the clashes between them.